# UrbanAirship error 400 with JSON string

Tags: php, urbanairship.com

I use last API V3 for sending a push to my app.
I use PHP library. 
Here is my code :

```
    $var = (string) json_encode($booking);

    UALog::setLogHandlers(array(new StreamHandler("php://stdout", Logger::DEBUG)));
    $airship = new Airship('secret', 'secret');
    $response = $airship->push()
        ->setAudience(P\all)
        ->setNotification(P\notification('test notification'))
        ->setDeviceTypes(P\all)
        ->send();

    return $response;
```

It works, but, if I want to push the $var instead of text 'test notification', I have an error 400. I have looked, $var contains a string (json formatted).

Is there a limit ? I can't send array, object, strings. I just an error 400. I use v0.2 connector : http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/php/0.2.0/push.html.

Comment: what is the error you are returned? generally the response contains an explanation of why it was rejected. what is in `$booking`?